# How to retrieve row index in gridview

Tags: c#, webforms

How to retrieve row index when selecting feild in in `gridview`

```
GridView.FindControl("lblReqId").rowIndex;
```

Comment: Where are you finding control? in DataBind Event, Row DataBind event or some other method event handler?

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal: Question is about `GridView` not `DataGridView`

Answer (score 1):

```
var ctrl = GridView.FindControl("lblReqId");
var idx = GridView.Controls.IndexOf(ctrl);
```

Comment: this will give index of ctrl (`lblReqId`) in this case not the index of row containing it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the `RowIndex` if this control is existing in each row cell of `GridView`. You might need to use `events` that fires for each row and in those event you can get RowIndex and ultimately your control `lblReqId` with reference to that `Row`.